# "Connection reset by peer: socket write error ERROR: Uploading file" Jenkins upload to nexus using nexus artifact uploader

Tags: windows, jenkins, upload, nexus

i'm having trouble with uploading zip file to nexus via jenkins using the nexus artifact uploader plugin

the weirdest part is that i'm uploading two files to Nexus, the first zip is being uploaded, no problems at all... but then, the second zip is doing the problems (the only difference between them, is their size, the second zip is bigger the 1GB)

my job is doing "gulp deploy" and compress it to a zip file, then, uploading it to nexus, and after that, i'm compiling a big (1.6GB) MSBuild project and compress (1.1GB) it too, but it won't upload it...

i'm using a windows slave to do the msbuild and the upload. when i try to upload the same file from the local centos to the out ip it works.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB6SR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad!
out of disk storage! so sorry!
the only thing that still bothers me is how the linux could have upload the same file?
maybe linux zip command is more efficient the power shell command?
Dunno... anyway... thanks